# What is an allone pattern?

Tags: usb

I am reading an article on the USB Spec and it mentions that "For CRC generation and checking, the shift registers in the generator and checker are seeded with an allones pattern." Here's the [full article](http://www.faculty.iu-bremen.de/birk/lectures/PC101-2003/14usb/FINAL%20VERSION/usb_protocol.html). What is an allones pattern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it should have been an "all ones pattern", as in "all high bits" for the seed value.

Comment: You know what? I was reading that spec article last night at like 2 am, and when I got up this morning and read "allones" again, I came to the same conclusion haha. Last night I was thinking it was some sort of predefined pattern like a Bayer pattern (and pronouncing it in my head like "alones").